# vba convert date dd.mm.yyyy to string in order to use in the file name

Tags: string, date, excel, vba

I am trying to grab data from a main excel file, copy parts into a new file, and save it with a date as string in the file name, format dd.mm.yyyy but I cannot get date converted to string in order to use it in the file name. Help much appreciated. I've found a hand full of solutions online but none of them work for me. Help much appreciated.

```
Sub invoicing()
Dim invoiceno As Variant 'but when grabbed from the file, it's string
Dim tourdate As Date
Dim final As String
Dim tourdate2 As String

Dim startrow As Variant
Dim endrow As Variant
startrow = 98
endrow = 170
Dim templatefilename As String
Dim newfilename As Variant
Dim oWorkbook As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet


Dim destinationpath  As String
destinationpath = CurDir
templatefilename = "Template Invoice.xlsx"


Set oWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(destinationpath & Application.PathSeparator &templatefilename)
oWorkbook.Activate

Set ws1 = oWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2015 client details")


With ws1
    .Cells(10, 3).Value = ws2.Cells(startrow, 16).Value     'invoice number
    .Cells(9, 3).Value = ws2.Cells(startrow, 25).Value      'enquiry date
    .Cells(11, 3).Value = ws2.Cells(startrow, 9).Value      'first name and last name
    .Cells(12, 3).Value = ws2.Cells(startrow, 30).Value     'pay date
    .Cells(12, 4).Value = ws2.Cells(startrow, 18).Value     'pay method
    .Cells(17, 2).Value = ws2.Cells(startrow, 12).Value     '# Adults, # Children, (Private)
    .Cells(17, 2).RowHeight = 50
    .Cells(17, 2).EntireRow.AutoFit
    .Cells(17, 3).Value = ws2.Cells(startrow, 23).Value     'tour date
    .Cells(17, 4).Value = ws2.Cells(startrow, 17).Value     'Amount
    .Cells(17, 5).Value = ws2.Cells(startrow, 17).Value     'Total Amount

End With
invoiceno = ws1.Cells(10, 3).Value

tourdate = ws1.Cells(17, 3).Value 'as date which cannot be used in file name in this form

tourdate2 = Format(tourdate, "dd.mm.yyyy")


'tourdate.Value = tourdate.Text
'tourdate.NumberFormat = "@"

newfilename = "Invoice" & " " & invoiceno & tourdate2
final = destinationpath & Application.PathSeparator & newfilename & tourdate
oWorkbook.SaveAs final, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
oWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: I think your problem is that you're trying to save a file with multiple dots '.' in the filename. Some operating systems allow this, but Windows has had a hard time with it (in my experience). As a long habit, I use underscores. so `newfilename = "Invoice" & " " & invoiceno & "_" & Format(tourdate, "dd_mm_yyyy")` should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, not enough reputation to comment...

Your line:

```
final = destinationpath & Application.PathSeparator & newfilename & tourdate
```

is using the date variable 'tourdate' and not the string variable 'tourdate2' (which is included in newfilename), so maybe change this line to:

```
final = destinationpath & Application.PathSeparator & newfilename
```

I don't think the multiple dots causes a problem anymore - unless you're still on Windows 98 or something like that.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying tourdate2 in the file name, didn't work.
I don't think the dots should be a problem as I do that all the time when not using VBA. I tried
tourdate2 = format(tourdate, "dd_mm_yyyy") and the error persists.
The code actually gets stuck on 
tourdate2 = Format(tourdate, "dd.mm.yyyy")
where the error is: Wrong number of arguments or wrong allocation or invalid property assignment

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work by fist reading the date value as .Text and then converting it to CStr()

```
      invoiceno = ws1.Cells(10, 3).Value
      tourdate = ws1.Cells(17, 3).Text
      tourdate = CStr(tourdate)
      newfilename = "Invoice" & " " & invoiceno & " " & tourdate & ".xlsx"
      newpdfname = "invoice" & " " & invoiceno & " " & tourdate & ".pdf"
      final = destinationpath & "Invoice Out 2015" & Application.PathSeparator & newfilename
      finalpdf = destinationpath & "invoice Out 2015" & Application.PathSeparator & newpdfname
      oWorkbook.SaveAs final, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
      ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=finalpdf
      oWorkbook.Close
```